# How to wrap errors from third party api?

Tags: javascript

I do use a third party API to manage auth operations.

The available methods returns promises, suppose a `createUser` method, I can call it this way:

```
this.auth.createUser(data).then(() => alert('user created'));
```

Ok so far.

If I do send invalid data or if I break some precondition the API throws some big error with a lot of data and information. The problem is that those errors are not user friendly.

I'm trying to wrap those methods, so I could throw a known error (specific tag) and give a better message to the user, but I was unable to do it so far.

I've built this snippet:

```js
class Auth {
    createUser(...args) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.log(...args);
                throw new Error('auth service throws some error with a lot of details and info not user friendly');
            }, 3000);
        });
    }
    log(...args) { console.log('this', ...args) }
}

const auth = new Auth();

Object.keys(auth).forEach(key => {
    if (typeof auth[key] === 'function') {
        const originalFunction = auth[key];
        auth[key] = function() {
            try {
                return originalFunction.apply(this, arguments);
            } catch (e) {
                this.log('error', e);
                throw new Error('error-auth-' + nameFunctionAsTag(key));
            }
        };
    } else {
        console.log(typeof auth[key]);
    }
});

function nameFunctionAsTag(name) {
    return name.replace(/(?!^)[A-Z]/g, c => '-' + c.toLowerCase());
}

auth.log('auth service');

auth.createUser(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

// expected: error-auth-create-user
// received: auth service throws some error with a lot of details and info not user friendly
```

As commented in the last two lines of code, I expected to catch the error and to receive `error-auth-create-user`, but I can't understand why it doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: A throw in setTimeout is different context than throw in new Promise. Use  reject instead

Comment: @charlietfl I got your point. but suppose some string argument which is expected by the API is null, and the API tries `null.toLowerCase()`, it will throw like my example, won't? I mean, how can I catch all possible errors/rejects in my code?

Comment: @charlietfl Now I didn't get your point... I've already used try catch. I can't change the API code (it is a third party code), the `createUser` above is just one example I've built to simulate the API error.

Comment: Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use resolve and reject in promise.

Here (your code):

```
try {
    return originalFunction.apply(this, arguments); // asynchronous because of setTimeOut
} catch (e) {
    this.log('error', e);
    throw new Error('error-auth-' + nameFunctionAsTag(key));
}
// 3 second later, trigger exception out of try/catch statement
```

What you can do:

```
function asyncError(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        // ... code
        reject(new Error('Error ...'));
        // ... code
    })

}

async function test(){
    try{
        const experiment = await asyncError();
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

Other way (catch without waiting):

```
function test2(){
    asyncError().catch((e) => console.log(e));
}
```

Comment: Your code is working, but I can't change de third party API code, what if they don't reject, but throw the error? Also, couldn't the async await syntax cause delay?

Comment: That's the goal of Promise object, make asynchronous and go back to the promise when reject or resolve is trigger

Comment: Just edited, you can loop without waiting after each call

Answer (score 1):

When you register a Promise, or even a setTimeout you are not calling that function within the same stack context. You are essentially telling the engine to register a callback and the system will invoke it with the correct parameters at a later time. Because of this, the error never bubbles up to a try/catch. You can utilize the await keyword inside an async function to suspend execution and return at a later time, maintaining the same context, which would retain the try/catch blocks use here. This is what you need to do here. Check out: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/the-definite-guide-to-handling-errors-gracefully-in-javascript-58424d9c60e6

Comment: Hm.. you are saying I can't test the `throw new Error()` inside a `setTimeout` because it is a new scope (makes sense)... then, How do I test my try catch? Is my only option here to use async await?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes try/catch blocks are purpose built for synchronous error handling in JS and unfortunately this is rarely useful. If your errors are async you need to utilize one of the async methods (error first callback, promise rejection, etc). async/await is the only way to use try/catch to handle async errors since it allows you to suspend execution of the stack. I encourage you to use await/async. It's not that hard to learn and a useful weapon against a potential future in callback hell.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the main problem: `Object.keys(auth)` returns empty array over class instance.

After changing it to `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(auth))` I could focus on the promise thing you all helped me out :)

My final working snippet ended this way:

```js
class Auth {
    createUser(...args) {
        return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
            this.log(...args);
            throw new Error('auth service throws some error with a lot of details and info not user friendly');
        });
    }
    log(...args) { console.log('this', ...args) }
}

const auth = new Auth();

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(auth)).forEach(key => {
    if (key === 'constructor') return;

    if (typeof auth[key] === 'function') {
        const originalFunction = auth[key];
        auth[key] = function() {
            return Promise.resolve()
                .then(() => originalFunction.apply(this, arguments))
                .catch(e => {
                    this.log('error', e.message);
                    throw new Error('error-auth-' + nameFunctionAsTag(key));
                });
        };
    }
});

function nameFunctionAsTag(name) {
    return name.replace(/(?!^)[A-Z]/g, c => '-' + c.toLowerCase());
}

auth.log('auth service');
auth.createUser(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).catch(e => console.log('final error:', e.message));
```

Thank you all for the help :)