# REST API test with Mocha & Chai- Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, chai

I made a very simple RESTful API that allows users to add, delete and update information about Hogwarts students.
Mongo acts as the persistence layer.

A GET request to `url/students` is supposed to return a list of all student objects. While writing the test for it I wrote

```
expect(res).to.equal('student list');
```

This is just for an initial check to make sure the test would fail but it isn't instead I get this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): AssertionError: expected { Object (domain, _events, ...) } to equal 'student list'
```

So it knows that the two values are different but instead of the test failing it's throwing an error.
I've pasted the full test code below.

```
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
chai.use(chaiHttp);
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('Students', async () => {
  describe('/GET students', () => {
    it('should GET all the students', async () => {
      chai.request('http://localhost:5000')
        .get('/students')
        .then(function (res) {
          try {
            expect(res).to.equal('hola');
          } catch (err) {
            throw err;
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          throw err; //this gets thrown
        })
    });
  });
});
```

And if you can show me the syntax of properly using async await for writing these tests please do that too.

Comment: .catch() after then(...). Note: async statement make sense only if you use the await statement

Comment: That doesn't work, I'll update the code above though. After I added the .catch, it caught the AssertionError but the point is why is there an AssertionError at all?

Comment: console.log res, if res != "hola", AssertionError is thrown

Comment: res is supposed to be an object, but the expect should fail the test, why should there be an error? Why is the test not failing ?

Comment: try a sample `it('should be true', ()=>expect(false).to.equal(true))` , if it works like you want and not your example, that's because of the promise. Maybe you can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520801/how-to-wrap-errors-from-third-party-api/55521013#55521013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test passes and logs the `"Unhandled promise rejection"` warning because the error is thrown within a `Promise` which just causes the `Promise` to reject.

Since the `Promise` is not returned or `await`-ed, the test completes successfully...

...and because nothing is waiting for or handling the rejected `Promise`, Node.js logs a warning.

**Details**

An error thrown in a test will fail the test:

```
it('will fail', function () {
  throw new Error('the error');
});
```

...but a rejected `Promise` will not fail the test if it is not returned or `await`-ed:

```
it('will pass with "Unhandled promise rejection."', function() {
  Promise.reject(new Error('the error'));
});
```

`.catch` [**returns a `Promise`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) so throwing in a `.catch` returns a rejected `Promise`, but if that `Promise` is not returned or `await`-ed then the test will also pass:

```
it('will also pass with "Unhandled promise rejection."', function() {
  Promise.reject(new Error('the error')).catch(err => { throw err });
});
```

...but if a rejected `Promise` is returned or `await`-ed then the test will fail:

```
it('will fail', async function() {
  await Promise.reject(new Error('the error'));
});
```

---

> And if you can show me the syntax of properly using async await for writing these tests please do that too.

For your test you can simplify it to this:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Students', async function() {
  describe('/GET students', function() {
    it('should GET all the students', async function() {
      const res = await chai.request('http://localhost:5000').get('/students');
      expect(res).to.equal('hola');  // <= this will fail as expected
    });
  });
});
```

**Details**

From the `chai-http` [doc](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/#dealing-with-the-response---promises):

> If `Promise` is available, `request()` becomes a Promise capable library

...so `chai.request(...).get(...)` returns a `Promise`.

You can simply `await` the `Promise` and the test will wait until the `Promise` resolves before continuing.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was extremely helpful.